# Prove A is a subset of B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the first time I have ever posted on this site, so bear with me please. Is this proof correct?

Prove

> $A \subseteq B \iff A \cap B^c =\emptyset$

$A \cap B^c =\emptyset$

$(A \cap B^c)^c = \emptyset^c$

$(A \cap B^c)^c = U$

$A^c \cup (B^c)^c = U$

$A^c \cup B = U$

$\to A = B$

$\to A \subseteq  B$

Comment: You mean $\emptyset$, not $\{\emptyset\}$. E.g. $A\cap B^c = \emptyset$, not "$A\cap B^c = \{\emptyset\}$". Please realize that $ \{\emptyset\}$ is NOT empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a small note first - {$\phi$} implies - a set with the element $\phi$ . To represent a null set, just say $\phi$.

Another note - $\phi^c = U$ and not $U^c$

Now, $A \cap B^c = \phi \implies $ If $ x \in A $ implies $x \notin B^c$

$\implies$ if $x \in A$ then $x \in B$. $\implies A\subseteq B$

In your proof you get $A^c \cup B = U = B^c \cup B$

So, $A$ is a subset of $B$.

You have to prove the other way too.

Comment: Thanks. Why the other way? I only set out to prove $A \subseteq B $

Comment: The other way because question has double implies

Comment: Okay, thanks! So one side must be transformed into the other side and vice versa.